# pinescript error code null, how do i fix it and what am I looking for

Tags: algorithm, compiler-errors, pine-script, tradingview-api

```
/@version=2
// This is a trading bot that finds breakouts in the market
// It uses the Bollinger Band and RSI indicators to identify potential breakouts

// Define the Bollinger Band settings
length = 20
stdDev = 2

// Define the RSI settings
rsiLength = 14
oversold = 30
overbought = 70

// Define the price data
priceData = close

// Calculate the Bollinger Band
bbLower = sma(priceData, length) - stdDev * stdev(priceData, length)
bbMiddle = sma(priceData, length)
bbUpper = sma(priceData, length) + stdDev * stdev(priceData, length)

// Calculate the RSI
rsi = rsi(priceData, rsiLength)

// If the price breaks out above the upper Bollinger Band and the RSI is not overbought,
// then enter a long position with a stop loss and take profit
if (priceData > bbUpper) and (rsi < overbought)
    strategy.entry("Long", true, stop = bbLower, take_profit = bbUpper)

// If the price breaks out below the lower Bollinger Band and the RSI is not oversold,
// then enter a short position with a stop loss and take profit
if (priceData < bbLower) and (rsi > oversold)
    strategy.entry("Short", false, stop = bbUpper, take_profit = bbLower)

// If the market is sideways, use a grid strategy to enter multiple positions
// and exit if the price reaches the Bollinger Band boundaries
strategy.grid("Grid", initial_balance = 1000, initial_positions = 10, 
              factor = 1.5, max_positions = 20, max_balance = 2000)
strategy.exit("Exit", "Grid", when = priceData <= bbLower or priceData >= bbUpper)
```

I keep getting error code null no matter what version I put it in and I'm so new to coding I don't even know what to look for in that error code. I'm not sure if trading =view has different language then what I'm using or if I cant use rsi or if the script I'm trying to make is even close to what pinescript should look like. I'm tearing my hair out at 4 am and help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You must add one more `/` to your version declaration so it should be `//@version=2`.

You are trying to use functions or arguments that don't exist. There is no `strategy.grid` function in pinescript.

`strategy.entry()` function does not have a argument called `take_profit`.

You should be using `strategy.exit()` for your take profits and stop losses.

Always check out the [reference manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/) and [user manual](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/index.html) when coding.